# Pytorch model doesn't learn identity function?

Tags: python, deep-learning, pytorch

I wrote some models in pytorch which was not able to learn anything even after many epochs. In order to debug the problem I made a simple model which models identity function of an input. The difficulty is this model also doesn't learn nothing despite training for 50k epochs,

```
import torch
import torch.nn as nn

torch.manual_seed(1)

class Net(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.input = nn.Linear(2,4)
        self.hidden = nn.Linear(4,4)
        self.output = nn.Linear(4,2)
        self.relu = nn.ReLU()
        self.softmax = nn.Softmax(dim=1)
        self.dropout = nn.Dropout(0.5)
    def forward(self,x):
        x = self.input(x)
        x = self.dropout(x)
        x = self.relu(x)
        x = self.hidden(x)
        x = self.dropout(x)
        x = self.relu(x)
        x = self.output(x)
        x = self.softmax(x)
        return x


X = torch.tensor([[1,0],[1,0],[0,1],[0,1]],dtype=torch.float)

net = Net()

criterion = nn.CrossEntropyLoss()

opt = torch.optim.Adam(net.parameters(), lr=0.001)


for i in range(100000):
    opt.zero_grad()
    y = net(X)
    loss = criterion(y,torch.argmax(X,dim=1))
    loss.backward()
    if i%500 ==0:
        print("Epoch: ",i)
        print(torch.argmax(y,dim=1).detach().numpy().tolist())
        print("Loss: ",loss.item())
        print()
```

Output

```
Epoch:  52500
[0, 0, 1, 0]
Loss:  0.6554909944534302

Epoch:  53000
[0, 0, 0, 0]
Loss:  0.7004914283752441

Epoch:  53500
[0, 0, 0, 0]
Loss:  0.7156486511230469

Epoch:  54000
[0, 0, 0, 0]
Loss:  0.7171240448951721

Epoch:  54500
[0, 0, 0, 0]
Loss:  0.691678524017334

Epoch:  55000
[0, 0, 0, 0]
Loss:  0.7301554679870605

Epoch:  55500
[0, 0, 0, 0]
Loss:  0.728650689125061
```

What is wrong with my implementation?

Comment: Not sure if that’s the problem, but if there are only two output neurons, use sigmoid as final activation function, and BCELoss.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There are a few mistakes:

1. **Missing `optimizer.step()`**:

`optimizer.step()` updates the parameters based on backpropagated gradients and other accumulated momentum and all.

2. **Usage of `softmax` with `CrossEntropy` Loss**:

Pytorch [`CrossEntropyLoss`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.nn.CrossEntropyLoss.html)  criterion combines `nn.LogSoftmax()` and `nn.NLLLoss()` in one single class. i.e. it applies softmax then takes negative log. So in your case you are taking **softmax(softmax(output))**. Correct way is use `linear` output layer while `training` and use `softmax` layer or just take `argmax` for prediction.

3. **High dropout value for small network**:

Which results in **underfitting**.

Here's the corrected code:

```
import torch
import torch.nn as nn

torch.manual_seed(1)

class Net(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.input = nn.Linear(2,4)
        self.hidden = nn.Linear(4,4)
        self.output = nn.Linear(4,2)
        self.relu = nn.ReLU()
        self.softmax = nn.Softmax(dim=1)
        # self.dropout = nn.Dropout(0.0)
    def forward(self,x):
        x = self.input(x)
        # x = self.dropout(x)
        x = self.relu(x)
        x = self.hidden(x)
        # x = self.dropout(x)
        x = self.relu(x)
        x = self.output(x)
        # x = self.softmax(x)
        return x

    def predict(self, x):
        with torch.no_grad():
            out = self.forward(x)
        return self.softmax(out)


X = torch.tensor([[1,0],[1,0],[0,1],[0,1]],dtype=torch.float)

net = Net()

criterion = nn.CrossEntropyLoss()

opt = torch.optim.Adam(net.parameters(), lr=0.001)


for i in range(100000):
    opt.zero_grad()
    y = net(X)
    loss = criterion(y,torch.argmax(X,dim=1))
    loss.backward()
    # This was missing before
    opt.step()
    if i%500 ==0:
        print("Epoch: ",i)
        pred = net.predict(X)
        print(f'prediction: {torch.argmax(pred, dim=1).detach().numpy().tolist()}, actual: {torch.argmax(X,dim=1)}')
        print("Loss: ", loss.item())
```

Output:

```
Epoch:  0
prediction: [0, 0, 0, 0], actual: tensor([0, 0, 1, 1])
Loss:  0.7042869329452515
Epoch:  500
prediction: [0, 0, 1, 1], actual: tensor([0, 0, 1, 1])
Loss:  0.1166711300611496
Epoch:  1000
prediction: [0, 0, 1, 1], actual: tensor([0, 0, 1, 1])
Loss:  0.05215628445148468
Epoch:  1500
prediction: [0, 0, 1, 1], actual: tensor([0, 0, 1, 1])
Loss:  0.02993333339691162
Epoch:  2000
prediction: [0, 0, 1, 1], actual: tensor([0, 0, 1, 1])
Loss:  0.01916157826781273
Epoch:  2500
prediction: [0, 0, 1, 1], actual: tensor([0, 0, 1, 1])
Loss:  0.01306679006665945
Epoch:  3000
prediction: [0, 0, 1, 1], actual: tensor([0, 0, 1, 1])
Loss:  0.009280549362301826
.
.
.
```